# Sugestão de como Exibir Dinamic Group do jasperSoft Stuio na mesma linha?

Tags: jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

Estou tentando fazer um relatório e gostaria de exibir do `detail` mais de 1 valor, portanto eles são dinâmicos. Exemplo da minha saída:

```
Grupo1

valor1 valor2 valor 3



Grupo2

valor 1 valor2 valor3
```

Objetivo:

```
Grupo1                     Grupo2  

valor1 valor 2 valor3       valor1 valor 2 valor 3
```

e assim por diante.  Tipo o `DataGrid` do `Primefaces`. Alguém poderia me dar uma sugestão? Desde já obrigado!

Comment: Gostaria que fosse exibidos horizontamente mais de 1  `Group` do `Jasper`. Tipo o `DataGrid` do `PrimeFaces`.Ainda não consegui!